# PostgreSQL trigger to replicate changes from one table to another

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a database named info. In the database I have 4 different tables `info1`, `info2`, `info3` and `info4`.

I want to create a stored procedure so that whenever I make changes in table `info1` (like `INSERT`, `DELETE` or `UPDATE`) the same changes should appear in the other three tables.

I am using PostgreSQL for this and I don't know how to perform this query.

Please explain it with an example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reading http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-trigger.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html can help a lot.

Comment: When seeking help on PostgreSQL (or anything, really) please mention the version you're working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to read the manual to understand what you are doing. @Michael provided links.

There are many different ways how you can go about this. Here are two typical examples for `UPDATE` and `DELETE`:

Create trigger function for UPDATE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_info1_upaft()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    UPDATE info2
    SET col1 = NEW.col1
    --more?
    WHERE info2.info1_id = NEW.info1_id;

    UPDATE info3
    SET col1 = NEW.col1
    --more?
    WHERE info3.info1_id = NEW.info1_id;

    -- more?
    RETURN NULL; -- because trigger is meant for AFTER UPDATE
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Create the trigger making use of it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upaft
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON info1
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_info1_upaft();
```

For DELETE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_info1_delaft()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM info2
    WHERE info1_id = OLD.info1_id;

    -- more?
    RETURN NULL; -- because trigger is meant for AFTER DELETE
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER delaft
  AFTER DELETE
  ON info1
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_info1_delaft();
```

Answer (score 1):

For such changes you should use trigger: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/triggers.html

You will have to create function that inserts/updates/deletes new data into other tables and then show PostgreSQL with `CREATE TRIGGER` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html  to call that function every time data in source table is changed.

Comment: hey michal, I know that. I have used trigger function for that. But I don't know the 'update' and 'delete' syntax for that. Could you please tell me how to update that

Comment: Hey dezso, I have read these articles. But in " postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-trigger.html " article they have mentioned only how 'select' query will word. I want to know about 'delete' and 'update'